# Is it valid to use static blocks as configurable filter?

Tags: java, design-patterns, static

I have a class to process events to broadcast

```
Public void processEvents(Event e) {
    saveEvent(e);
   broadcast(e);
}
```

However a requirement comes up that certain events (foo, bar, baz) should not be broadcasted. However this list should be configurable as tomorrow we may need to prevent ‘foobar’ from being broadcasted

To filter them I created a static initializer block:

```
Private static final Set<Events> filter = new HashSet<>();
Static {
   Filter.put(“foo”);
  Filter.put(“bar”);
  Filter.put(“baz”);
}

Public void processEvents(Event e) {
    saveEvent(e);
   if (!filter.contains(e)) {
       broadcast(e);  
   }
}
```

1. Is this a valid / common use of static intializaer block ?
2. Is there any better / other common way of creating such a configurable filter.

Comment: If `filter` is used in a non-static method, why do you feel the need to make it `static`? --- Also, if you hard-code the static initializer block, how does that make it "configurable"? `hardCode != configurable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use both a static block and the `static` keyword with the filter (it isn't being called from a static context), you simply could perform these actions in a controller of your class:

```
public class Processor {
    private final Set<String> filter;

    public Processor() {
        initialiseFilter();
    }

    private void initialiseFilter() {
        filter = new HashSet<>();
        filter.addAll(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz"));
    }
}
```

Also, consider the way with a [`HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet-java.util.Collection-) constructor to initialise on the spot:

```
private final Set<String> filter = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> > 1. Is this a valid / common use of static intializaer block ?

Static blocks are also called "static initializers", so it is okay to initialize variables inside it.

> > 2. Is there any better / other common way of creating such a configurable filter.

The better way is to configure the filter contents external to the application, so that any modification to the filter list happens outside of the application and does not require code recompilation.